# re.findall not finding

Tags: regex, python-3.x

```
d = (re.findall(r'style=3D"outline: medium none;">(.*?)</h3>', b))
```

Works great the first time but it doesn't give me all the results that are in the file.  I only get back one result.  I'm using this with an mht file that I have to save that way to be able to get everything from the website that I'm trying to get.  I have several different instances of re.findall and each and everyone of them responds the same way, only grabbing the first match and not putting anything else into the list.  How do I change this to get this to work correctly?

I'll add in, also, this is a series of files where some files may only have 3 matches while other files may have up to 30 matches. No more than 30 at the present time...unfortunately.

Comment: You should show an example input. If I had to guess `(.*?)` matches everything until your last `</h3>`, (partial fix:`([^<]*)`).Also this can be a prime example why you don't parse XML/HTML with regular expressions but use a proper XML/HTML parser, like lxml.

Comment: Can you parse the html from a saved file.  I can't/don't want to work with the file directly from the internet, rather from a saved file.  It'll save a ton of time to do the whole process the way I'm doing it.  I'm fighting ???php??? something that doesn't show the data until you click on an item on the screen and then it will pop down the data or send you to google maps. I'm just doing the physical work while I have an internet connection and then want to use the program to go through the saved files when I get home.

Comment: I just tried replacing (.*?) with ([^<]*) and nothing changed.

Comment: Of course you can parse HTML files from disc, regarding your other question, it depends on the website, if the data gets lazily loaded, then you need an internet connection, if not, the data is already in your HTML file.

Comment: @dav1d `.*?` is a non-greedy match. It won't consume  `</h3>`.

Comment: Can you post an example? You should be able to grab a file with two of these and with generous use of the delete key, produce something small and demonstrable.

Comment: @tdelaney you're right, too tired. Still point stands, just use a HTML parser and/or show at least some example input.

Comment: The regex you show won't match XML. What format is this data in?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the answer to the problem.  Assume nothing.  OOPS!  Looking the other re.findalls was picking everything up except the first one and the final one.  I did find the first one does change it's  statement from the what the original  statement was.  I haven't fully tried it yet but it does make me feel safe enough to say I have answered the question.  Dumb me.  Should have checked and not just expected the syntax to remain the same between occurences.